# Convert any email address into an image in .net or Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net

I am looking for a tool that will convert any email address into an image. Instead of actual text you'll have an image with your email address inside of it. This way spambots can't read your email address.

Are there any .NET or javascript libraries that do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by obscuring email addresses? If you're trying to avoid spam there are better solutions, such as using good spam filters (like gmail), or simply not displaying email addresses on your site in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple project that you can do your work

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/AspNetCreateTextImage.aspx

Search for more on [google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=asp.net+create+image+text&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=)